# Lower case and Upper case in Solr keyword

Tags: search, jakarta-ee, solr, lucene

Im using Solr 3.5.0, and in Schema I have enabled the LowerCaseFilterFactory in all needed fields, bbut When I search for example "shirts" im able to get the results, also when I search for "SHIRTS" i'm able to get expected results, but when I try to search with "shiRTs" its not giving the results. I know I'm missing some thing in Schema.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Jeyaprakash.

Comment: You should add LowerCaseFilterFactory while indexing and querying.Maybe you miss one.If you share your fieldType it will be helpfull to give appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the same analysers and filters at both index and query time, so the the queries you search for match the tokens index.

As in your case - 
If you apply the Lower case filter at index time but not at query time :-
Index token will be `shirts`, However as the search query is not analyzed `SHIRTS` or even `Shirts` will not match indexed `shirts` token.

The same would apply if you are using stemmers, stopwords or other filters.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers

> Analyzers are components that pre-process input text at index time
>   and/or at search time. It's important to use the same or similar
>   analyzers that process text in a compatible manner at index and query
>   time. For example, if an indexing analyzer lowercases words, then the
>   query analyzer should do the same to enable finding the indexed words.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to do this?

For example: the filter `solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory` is applied in the schema for text_en_splitting. How to apply this to query?

Comment: Did you mean `<analyzer type="index">` and `<analyzer type="query">` in the schema? I have this but still no effect... Query still doesnt do it as mentioned in the question